# Vertex data type in Graphchi

Tags: graph, types, vertex, graphchi

Can we make string as the vertex data type; it is mentioned that we cannot use dynamic data type but suppose I want to keep on adding some data to the vertex how shall I do?
I was thinking of using array but size is not known; so would using string cause any issues? ( I will keep on concatenating to the string)

Answer (score 1):

Although the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/graphchi/wiki/CreatingGraphChiApplications) explicitly forbids non-POD types (disallowing `std::vector<>`, `std::string` and the like), it seems to be possible to make it work (based on errors reported by the compiler and the runtime in rev. 278):

- Make sure your type has a default constructor
- Implement the `graphchi::parse<>()` template function specialized to your type

For example, (ab)using a vector to store a singlular int (*disclaimer*: example written for proof of concept, not for efficiency):

```
class VertexData
{
  std::vector<int> data;

public:
  // default ctor
  VertexData()
  {
    setData(0);
  }

  // convenience ctor
  VertexData(int v)
  {
    setData(v);
  }

  void setData(int v)
  {
    data.clear();
    data.push_back(v);
  }

  int getData()
  {
    return data.at(0);
  }
};

namespace graphchi
{
  template<>
  void parse<VertexData>(VertexData& vd, const char* s)
  {
    // NOTE: stoi is C++11 feature, use your favorite C++03 equivalent if needed
    int x = std::stoi(s);
    vd.setData(x);
  }
}
```

Note that the default binary output (*.vout) will write the binary contents of VertexData itself, which means raw pointers in case of `vector<>` and other dynamic datatypes (hence the documentation's forbiddance).  To see the actual values, follow the instructions in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112543/writing-output-to-a-file-in-graphchi) (using `graphchi::foreach_vertices<>()` with an output functor).

**Update**

While the above approach might seem to work, it should not be used for a number of reasons, including:

- The dynamic memory handling requires all data to fit into memory, which might not be the case for large dataset
- Due to the way the vertex and edge objects are written-to/read-from disk, there is no guarantee for the destructors to be called for any vertex/edge objects, which can (at the minimum) lead to resource (e.g. memory) leak.

In short: the documentation has its good reasons to forbid this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Limited support for dynamic vectors as vertex data type has been recently added to Graphchi: http://code.google.com/p/graphchi/wiki/DynamicVertexData