# Extracting plain text output from binary file

Tags: graphchi

I am working with Graphchi's pagerank example: https://github.com/GraphChi/graphchi-cpp/wiki/Example-Apps#pagerank-easy

The example app writes a binary file with vertex information that I would like to read/convert to a plan text file (to later call into R or some other language).

The documentation states that:

"GraphChi will write the values of the edges in a binary file, which is easy to handle in other programs. Name of the file containing vertex values is GRAPH-NAME.4B.vout. Here "4B" refers to the vertex-value being a 4-byte type (float)."

The 'easy to handle' part is what I'm struggling with - I have experience with high level languages but not C++ or dealing with binary files. I have found a few things through searching stackoverflow but no luck yet in reading this file. Ideally this would be done through bash or python.

thanks very much for your help on this.

Update: `hexdump graph-name.4B.vout | head -5` gives:

`0000000 999a 3e19 7468 3e7f 7d2a 3e93 d8e0 3ec4
0000010 cec6 3fe4 d551 3f08 eff2 3e54 999a 3e19
0000020 999a 3e19 3690 3e8c 0080 3f38 9ea3 3ef5
0000030 b7d6 3f66 999a 3e19 10e3 3ee1 400c 400d
0000040 a3df 3e7c 999a 3e19 979c 3e91 5230 3f18`

Comment: If you could post more info on the format of the binary file, that would be helpful. Do you need to parse the `float` values too? If you only need the `string` names, can you use [strings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)? What exactly needs to end up in the plain text file?

Comment: thanks - from what I understand, the final file should contain two columns, the `vertex id` (an integer) and the `pagerank value` (a float). The number of rows is the number of total vertices (which I know). Would a hexdump of the binary file be useful?

Comment: Yes, a hex dump would help. If's it's long, then just the first 5 vertices-worth should be fine.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty opaque. You'll probably have to find out more from GraphChi about what the particular bytes in the output represent, but parsing them in Java, C++, or Bash shouldn't be hard, once you know the format. Also, might it be possible to output plain-text directly, as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112543/writing-output-to-a-file-in-graphchi)?

Comment: Thanks for the input @pieman72 much appreciated. I was able to change the C++ code to output a text file as you suggest from within the GraphChi pagerank script, but I get some bug when trying to print all the vertices (it works for a smaller number okay). Hence trying to access the binary file directly. I'll get in touch with GraphChi and see if they can provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code how you can use GraphCHi to write the output out as a string:
  https://github.com/GraphChi/graphchi-cpp/wiki/Vertex-Aggregators

But the array is simple byte array. Here is example how to read it in python:

```
import struct
from array import array as binarray 
import sys

inputfile = sys.argv[1]

data = open(inputfile).read()
a = binarray('c')
a.fromstring(data)

s = struct.Struct("f")

l = len(a)

print "%d bytes" %l

n = l / 4

for i in xrange(0, n):
    x = s.unpack_from(a, i * 4)[0]
    print ("%d %f" % (i, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble.  Luckily I work with a bunch of network engineers who helped me out!  On Mac Linux, the following command works to print the 4B.vout data one line per node, with the integer values the same as is given in the summary file.  If your file is called eg, filename.4B.vout, then some command line perl gets you:

cat filename.4B.vout | LANG= perl -0777 -e '$,=\"\n\"; print unpack(\"L*\",<>),\"\";'

Edited to add: this is for the assignments of connected component ID and community ID, written implicitly the 1st line is the ID of the node labeled 0, the 2nd line is the node labeled 1 etc.  But I am copypasting here so I'm not sure how it would need to change for floats.  It works great for the integer values per node.